# Simple Example of Apache Camel and Mina (Karaf) throws CamelExchangeException: Cannot write body

Tags: exception, apache-servicemix

I have taken the simple activemq-camel-blueprint example from ServiceMix 4.4.0, and added in a Mina TCP socket to read from ASCII lines.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route>
        <from uri="mina:tcp://localhost:4001?textline=true&amp;sync=false" />
        <bean ref="NMEAString" method="ingest" />
        <to uri="activemq:queue:LOG.ME"/>
    </route>
    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:queue:LOG.ME" />
        <to uri="log:ExampleActiveMQRouterBlueprint" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

I am running the example within Karaf. All the NMEAString does is print out the object to STDOUT.

I run a little program to push an ASCII file to a socket connection. It pushes in the whole file (~40) lines in a few milliseconds.

I see a STDOUT printout within Karaf at about 30 seconds between lines. 
I am getting the following exceptions within my servicemix.log file:

Does anyone know what this exception means and why it is throwing it with such a simple
example?

> org.apache.camel.CamelException: org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: Cannot write body. Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.mina.MinaConsumer$ReceiveHandler.exceptionCaught(MinaConsumer.java:91)[186:org.apache.camel.camel-mina:2.8.3]
>       at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain$TailFilter.exceptionCaught(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:564)[187:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.mina:1.1.7.5]
>       at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.callNextExceptionCaught(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:345)[187:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.mina:1.1.7.5]
>       at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.access$1000(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:53)[187:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.mina:1.1.7.5]
>       at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.exceptionCaught(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:643)[187:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.mina:1.1.7.5]
>       at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter.processEvent(ExecutorFilter.java:224)[187:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.mina:1.1.7.5]
>       at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter$ProcessEventsRunnable.run(ExecutorFilter.java:264)[187:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.mina:1.1.7.5]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)[:1.6.0_29]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)[:1.6.0_29]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)[:1.6.0_29]
>   Caused by: org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: Cannot write body. Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.mina.MinaHelper.writeBody(MinaHelper.java:55)[186:org.apache.camel.camel-mina:2.8.3]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.mina.MinaConsumer$ReceiveHandler.messageReceived(MinaConsumer.java:148)[186:org.apache.camel.camel-mina:2.8.3]
>       at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceived(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:570)[187:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.mina:1.1.7.5]
>       at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:299)[187:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.mina:1.1.7.5]
>       at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.access$1100(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:53)[187:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.mina:1.1.7.5]
>       at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:648)[187:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.mina:1.1.7.5]
>       at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter.processEvent(ExecutorFilter.java:220)[187:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.mina:1.1.7.5]
>       ... 4 more

Answer (score 0):

L.S.,

Just tried this myself with Apache ServiceMix 4.4.0 and the blueprint file below works fine for me, so I suspect that your bean somehow invalidates or removes the message body (e.g. by calling getOut() on the Exchange and creating an empty message or something like that).

Could you try removing the bean from your route to ensure that it is really the cause of the problem?  If it is, feel free to post the code of the bean itself and we can help you look for  the problem that's lurking in there...

Regards,

Gert

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <route>
    <from uri="mina:tcp://localhost:4001?textline=true&amp;sync=false" />
    <to uri="log:test-read-stream"/>
    <to uri="activemq:queue:LOG.ME"/>
  </route>
  <route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue:LOG.ME" />
    <to uri="log:ExampleActiveMQRouterBlueprint" />
  </route>
</camelContext>

</blueprint>
```